# Elements added to a vector of pairs of ints and vectors of strings are cleared at function return

Tags: c++, vector

I'm attempting to store a list of strings into a vector inside of a pair, inside of a vector of said pairs.

Attempting to access said inner vector of the pair (which does exist) shows that there are 0 elements inside that vector.

When running the debugger, the `initializationTest` function indeed adds 4 strings to the inner vector, and those strings can be seen when hovering over the `info` variable; at least while I'm still inside that specific function. As soon as I step out of that function, the strings are gone.

What's going on?

I have managed to recreate the behavior using the following code:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>>> info;
std::string teststr = "HAHAHA,";

void initializationTest() {
    for (auto t : info) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            t.second.push_back(teststr);
        }
    }
    // by the end of this function, there are 4 items inside t.second
}

// this function seems to work okay
void pairInit() {
    std::vector<std::string> vs;
    std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>> p(0, vs);

    // Using info.push_back(p); doesn't change anything
    info.push_back(std::make_pair(0, vs));
}

// this function is returning true when it should return false, as no values
// have been modified; by the time i get to here, there are no values
// remaining inside t.second, but info does in fact contain the pair 
// with a "first" value of 0.
bool validateInfoExists() {
    for (std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>> t : info) {
        for (std::string s : t.second) {
            printf("Validating");
            printf(s.c_str());
            printf("\n");
            if (s == teststr) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    pairInit();
    initializationTest();

    // t is true; intended behavior is that it be false.
    bool t = validateInfoExists();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (auto t : info) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        t.second.push_back(teststr);
    }
}
```

Inside this loop, `t` is a copy of an element from `info`. When you call `t.second.push_back` you are modifying this copied object. It has no effect on the elements inside `info`. Changing `t` to a reference will fix your problem.

```
for (auto& t : info)
```

Comment: Well, now I just feel silly. I can't believe I missed something that obvious. When I use `for (std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>> t : info)`, does that also create a copy instead of a reference?

Comment: Yes, you will still need the reference keyword to fix. `auto` just gets the type, nothing else.

Comment: @Aify: Yes. Although in the case of that loop (in the code you presented) you are not modifying the object. So you shouldn't notice a difference in the correctness of the program (although you might notice a difference in the performance). I would suggest using a const reference in that case. Either `std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>> const& t`, or simply `auto const& t`.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help!